# seleccionar un elemento en un DataGridView

Tags: c#

muy buenas, estoy intentando seleccionar un elemento de un DataGridView, sin embargo, no puedo obtener el item seleccionado debido a que la función 'SelectedItem' no me aparece
el código acontinuación

```
private void myData_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid data = sender as DataGrid;
        DataRowView view = myData.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    }
```

la captura de pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llenando el grid? usando listas, arreglos, etc.

Comment: mediante la base de datos HR que viene por defecto en oracle

Comment: porqué conviertes el sender a datagrid si luego ni lo usas?

Comment: de hecho cometí un error en esa foto, lo hacía era con el data, pero luego lo puse con el data y seguía el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe esa propiedad, porque no intentas usar

[DataGridView.SelectedRows Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=netframework-4.5)

junto con la propiedad

[DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=netframework-4.5#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRow_DataBoundItem)

algo como ser

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows){
        var view = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row
        //resto codigo
   }
}
```

Si solo vas a permiti ua unica seleccion recuerda asinar

[DataGridView.MultiSelect Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect?view=netframework-4.5)

entonces podrias usar

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0){
      return;
   }

   var row = DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
   var view = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row

   //resto codigo

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
private void myData_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (myData.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow dr = myData.SelectedRows[0]; 

            }
    }
```

**Aclaración:** Aquí no estas seleccionando una row. Solo estas obteniendo la que esta seleccionada actualmente.

Para seleccionar una fila debes hacer algo así:

```
this.grid.Rows[int index].Selected = true;
```